# What are some of the most 'pure' object-oriented languages?

Tags: ruby, oop, block, smalltalk

A recent introduction to Smalltalk has enlightened me on the application and benefits of a 'pure' object oriented style. I'd previously seen the benefits of this in Ruby, though the presence of non object oriented `if`, `unless` etc. constructs seemed like it didn't carry things all the way through.

By pure here, I'm talking about things like 'everything is an object' (including functions via blocks or something similar) and no procedural-style flow control, instead using flow control methods on booleans & collections.

Yet, even in a language like Smalltalk some things stand out as not being object oriented. For example it doesn't seem possible to do variable assignment without using special syntax (:= instead of an 'is:' or similar method) and returning values from a function seems to require the ^ operator which doesn't seem to 'belong' to any object.

Are there any languages that carry this style even further?

Comment: What is the benefit of purity? Purity makes Haskell have a significantly higher learning curve than other functional languages because monads are so hard to understand from a procedural point of view.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, but monads are *awesome* once you get them. This question, on the other hand, seems like carrying the purity thing a bit far... Sure, you could drop return values and instead require that kind of communication to go through object state (call a method it results in nothing, then use `self.result`), but there's a reason we programmers usually try to keep the scope of everything as small as possible. Plus, it would break method chaining as there's no return value, unless you define some object property to be that value, but then we're back to magic. And the list goes on.

Comment: I totally recognize that purity in this regard can make things pretty verbose and potentially not performant, but there's also a significant benefit in a language having a very small and consistent ruleset. That said, I'd love to find a language that has taken things to the extreme even if just for a good example of too much of a good thing.

Comment: Why do you think that if statements are "non object oriented"?  You need if statements, it has nothing to do with object orientation.

Comment: You do need flow control, but the procedural if statement is not the only way to accomplish this. For example, in Smalltalk you can instead do:

condition ifTrue: [//true block] ifFalse: [//false block]

where condition is a Boolean object.

Comment: Variable assignment seeming weird in Smalltalk was an intentional design choice. Variable assignment is a different kind of thing on a different level from sending a message to an object, so they wanted the language to call attention to that.

Comment: Just as a note, `^ foo` may be regarded as syntactic sugar for `thisContext return: foo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a long time Smalltalker I (compared to lots of other answers here) understand what you are after - and the "self" language does go a bit further, at least when it comes to assignments. Not having programmed in self I can't comment it further than that. Another newer language similar to self is Slate, also prototypical and also uses message sends for assignments.

Answer (score 2):

Eiffel, Smalltalk, and Ruby 
http://www.jvoegele.com/software/langcomp.html

Comment: Smalltalk was discussed and dismissed in the question. Ruby is much more hybrid than Smalltalk (for instance, it has functional features such as `call/cc`). Please read the question.

Comment: That link is actually a great resource.

Comment: it WAS a great resource ten years ago. Java has generics since about 2003.

Comment: @delnan: `call/cc` is unnecessary in any environment that exposes the call stack directly, as Squeak and Pharo do. And `call/cc` is a bad idea anyway: partial continuations, please.